# Webserver access from Outside Network

Tags: router, dns, ip, webserver

I have a Watchguard firewall router with a public IP address and I have a web server in my internal network (192.168.1.5) and i have a domain name (http://www.forexample.com).

We can access to to our company website from internal IP address (http://webserver:81/index.php) which root file is loated in C:\wamp\www.

How can i access from outside network using domain name since i have watchguard router with public and private ip address? What are the setting do i have to configure? Please Advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First make your servers ip static if not already.  Then from routers control page make it route incoming traffic to your servers ip(DMZ).
You need to register name server to your domain ex. Afraid dns. Then link it to your ip.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to ensure that the webserver is accessible. Either via [port forwarding](http://portforward.com/), or by allowing your server to be the outward-facing device in your network.

When that is done, you need to let the internet know that this is accessible via a domain name by associating it with a publicly available [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name). This can be achieved by buying a domain name for it, or by setting up a subdomain on an existing domain name that you have access to use. When that is done, you need to set up [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) records to point towards the IP address of your webserver.

If you are on a dynamic IP, you would most likely need to use a [dynamic DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) provider, to ensure that the DNS record for your webserver is updated if the IP changes.

---

These are the general steps required. For specifics I will need more details about your setup:

- Do you have a domain or subdomain that you want to use?
- Are you able to set up your webserver as [DMZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_%28computing%29), or will you have to rely on port forwarding?
- Does your ISP provide you with a static IP?